# add : after the first column with sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have configuration file with similar text:

```
BACKUP=nfs://NASserver/vol/FS01/share/
```

I need to extract the fields after // ,but add : after the first column
like this:

```
NASserver:/vol/FS01/share/
```

I have tried:

```
cat file.conf |awk -F"//" /BACKUP/'{print $2}'|awk -F"/" '{print $1":""/"$2"/"$3"/"$4}'
```

which works and produce :

```
NASserver:/vol/FS01/share/
```

but this will work in the a case that NAS name will need to print $5 it will not work:

meaning: for example if BACKUP string contain the 5'th fild or more this my awk will not work

i.e

```
BACKUP=nfs://NASserver/vol/FS01/share/folder1/folder2
```

how can I get same result with awk for any length of the BACKUP string 
I will get

```
NASserver:/full volumes path
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** oneliner solution, tested on gawk v5.0.0.

Works under the assumption that you only have 1 instance of "//" per row and you are interested in what follows. Uses pipe.

```
awk -F"//" '{print $2}' file.conf | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";OFS="/"}{$1 = $1":"; print}'
```

output:

```
NASserver:/vol/FS01/share/
```

Answer (score -1):

If your format is fixed say: "BACKUP=nfs://...." then this following code will do for any length

```
cat file.conf | sed 's#BACKUP=nfs://\([^/]\+\)\(.*\)#\1:\2#g'
```

If, your format may vary, I mean for example: "FTP=ftp://...", then

```
cat file.conf | awk -F'//' '{print $NF}' | sed 's#^\([^/]\+\)\(.*\)$#\1:\2#g'
```

Comment: There is no need to `cat` your file with awk: `awk -F'//' '{print $NF}' file.conf  | sed 's#^\([^/]\+\)\(.*\)$#\1:\2#g'`